# Why Vertical Align is working on jsfiddle

Tags: html, css

Same source, no difference, but Vertical Align only works on jsfiddle. Please help me to answer.
This is HTML Source, it doesn't work on Chrome:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
        .checkboxOfField
        {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            height: 40px;
            line-height: 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="checkboxOfField">
        <input style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" />
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/UghzT/
It works on Chrome. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because of Quirksmode?

Add a Doctype!

Comment: Yes, tested it locally on Safari `6.0.3` on OS X `10.8.3` without doctype; then it ignores the vertical aligning. Adding it makes the vertical align pop in again. +1

Comment: the vertical align ain't doing anything, it's the line-height which sets the checkbox in the middle...

Answer (score 1):

Why adding the style to the `input`? It isn't doing anything.
The `input` has a `type="checkbox"` attribute. Thus `text-align:center;` is a bit strange because there will never be text inside. Even the `vertical-align` property does not belong there. There isn't anything inside the checkbox to align...

The CSS code you have will do in order to align everything in the span in the middle.
Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UghzT/1/). I deleted the ´style` attribute and it still works great.